# How to setup a apache proxy relay that works with ssl requests?

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, proxypass

In our usecase we try to hide the proxy authentication of an 3th party proxy with an apache proxy, as the cloud server provider is not compatible with ip whitelisting.

This means that from our server we try to use an proxy. while the proxy needs ip whitelisted verification.

Therefor trying to setup an proxy that forwards to the external proxy, where our proxy has an static ip.

First thing we did, setup on our AWS box an apache server with only 
these configurations

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On

<VirtualHost *:8001>
  ProxyPass / http://yyy.externalprovider.io:8230/ Keepalive=On
  ProxyPassReverse / http://yyy.externalprovider.io:8230/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works completely fine with both http and https. But the requests are still coming from our server ip.

After this i can achieve to get things running with normal http,but https gives always an 502 Gateway error. with the following configuration

```
ProxyRequests Off
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify None
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<VirtualHost *:8001>
  ProxyPass / http://yyy.externalprovider.io:8230/ Keepalive=On
  ProxyPassReverse / http://yyy.externalprovider.io.io:8230/
</VirtualHost>
```

In our apache2.conf i already configured ProxyTimeout to be set to 300, as that's the most mentioned solution trough-out the internet.

Is there somebody that understand why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Removing all SSLProxy* Statements and adding in RemoteProxy with ProxyRequest On, fixed it.

Comment: It's great that you found a solution and posted it yourself! Do you think you could post the entire configuration that made it work? It'll make it more helpful for other people who might have the same problem to.